# setState getting updated multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I am incrementing a counter by setState() of React using a setInterval method. But for every intervals the application is updating multiple times.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Arrival extends Component {
state = {
    count: 0,
    limitTo: 6
  }
  render() {
    try {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          limitTo: this.state.limitTo + 6
        })
        console.log(this.state)
      }, 5000);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  return()
}
}
```

In the first 5 seconds, the state is getting updated once.

In the next 5 seconds, the state is getting updated 2 times.

In the next 5 seconds, the state is getting updated 4 times. and so on...

I want the state to only get updated once every 5 seconds.

Comment: move `setInterval()` to `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 1):

when the state update, the component will be also updated and re-render, hence the `setInterval` should not be inside `render` method. You can do this instead:

```
class Arrival extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    limitTo: 6
  };

  interval = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          limitTo: this.state.limitTo + 6
        });
        console.log(this.state);
      }, 5000);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit busy-flower-wj0x5]

> Note: reminded by @FrankerZ, you should also clean up the interval when the component unmounts, otherwise the clock will keep ticking ;)

Comment: You should include cleanup code if the component unmounts

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` is called in `render()` method. This means that:

1. It will be set off the first time it is rendered. *Timers ticking: 1*.
2. After 5 seconds, it will fire and change the state. It means the component will need to rerender.
3. Rendering starts another timer, since `setInterval()` is called in `render()` method. *Timers ticking: 2*.
4. Another 5 seconds pass. First timer ticks again, which causes component to rerender due to state change. Another timer is set off. *Timers ticking: 3*.
5. Second timer ticks for the first time. Another rerender happens and causes a 4th timer to be started. *Timers ticking: 4*.
6. Ad infinitum

To solve this, move `setInterval` to [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) as recommended by another answer to ensure the timer is started once only, not on each `render`.